# Display something while the DOM/Isotope is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

### The goal

Display a loading gif while the DOM/Isotope is loading.

### The problem

When someone access my application it is possible to see the Isotope/DOM struturing on the screen. I mean, it is possible to see the elements organizing — this is very unprofessional and ugly.

### A bit of my code

**Isotope (jQuery) — its loaded when the window load:**

```
    jQuery("ul.products-list").isotope({
        itemSelector: "li",
        masonry: {
            gutterWidth: 15
        }
    });
```

### What I have

Nothing. I do not even know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive that isotope has a callback. Use it to fade in the products

```
ul.products-list {
   display:none;
}


jQuery("ul.products-list").isotope({
    itemSelector: "li",
    masonry: {
        gutterWidth: 15
    }
}, function(){ $(this).fadeIn() });
```

Comment: Perfect! But instead of `$(this).fadeIn();`, the solution for me was `$(this).children("li").fadeIn();`. By the way, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Masonry adds the "masonry" css class to the container. So you could do it with css:

```
ul.products-list {
   background-image:url(loading.gif);
}
ul.products-list.masonry {
   background-image:none;
}
ul.products-list li {
 display:none;
}

ul.products-list.masonry li {
 display:block;
}
```